# How could we use tuple in c++98?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++98

I am new to c++ while I am also required to use c++98 due to a package named Gurobi. In my project, I need to construct a map from tuples of 7 integers to integer:

```
map<tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int,int>,int>
```

While in C++98:

```
#include <tuple>
```

Already introduces error. How could I build this map in c++98 (or is there any walk around? but the map structure is necessary)? Thank you:)

Comment: Use `boost::tuple`.

Comment: Oh. thank you. Does it require separate installation?

Comment: Yes. http://boost.org

Comment: ..or `std::tr1::tuple` of TR1.

Comment: Your compiler might also provide `std::tr1::tuple`, e.g. for GCC `#include <tr1/tuple>`

Comment: oh!! Thank you all so much. I succeed in defining my tuples. Thank you:)